# PHP form sending with variables issue

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, ckeditor

I am struggling with PHP AJAX CKEDITOR and MySQL as I would like to save everything from the screen (includes input text boxes) and CKeditor text to an mysql by pressing a button at the bottom.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php include("db_connect.php"); ?>
<?php include("menu.php"); ?>
<h1>New Project</h1>

<form method="post" action="">
    New project name:<input type="text" name="pr-name" placeholder="new project name..."><br/>
    New project end date:<input type="text" name="pr-end" placeholder="date..."><br/>
    New project type:
    <select name="pr-menu">
        <?php 
        $listdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lists WHERE tag='prtype' ORDER BY listing ASC");
        while($listresult = mysql_fetch_array($listdata))
    {
        $link = '';
        if($listresult['listing'] != '...') {
            $link = $listresult['value'] . ".php";
            echo "<option value='$link'>${listresult['listing']}</option>";
        }

    }
    ?>
</select>

<div id="page">
    <!-- container for loaded page -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("select[name=pr-menu]").change(function() {
        var url = $("option:selected", this).val();
        // Load a page to the container
        $("#page").load(url);
    });
</script>

</form>

<?php
if($_REQUEST["submit"] == "continue ->")
{
$prname = mysql_real_escape_string ($_REQUEST["pr-name"]);
$prend = mysql_real_escape_string ($_REQUEST["pr-end"]);
$prmenu = mysql_real_escape_string ($_REQUEST["pr-menu"]);
$prcontent = mysql_real_escape_string ($_REQUEST["pagecontent"]);

$sql = "INSERT INTO projects (name,enddate, sel, content) VALUES('$prname','$prend', '$prmenu', '$prcontent')";
mysql_query($sql);
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Which code select different php files to extend the form. One of the form has CKEDITOR as well.

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="pagecontent"  id="pagecontent"></textarea>

<?php
include_once "ckeditor/ckeditor.php";
$CKEditor = new CKEditor();
$CKEditor->basePath = 'ckeditor/';

// Set global configuration (will be used by all instances of CKEditor).
   $CKEditor->config['width'] = 600;   
// Change default textarea attributes
   $CKEditor->textareaAttributes = array(“cols” => 80, “rows” => 10);

   $CKEditor->replace("pagecontent");

?>
<input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="continue ->"/>
```

And I would like to put the up two input AND the edited CKEDITOR content in a SQL...

I just can't find the solution how to link these together... and I have spent a few hours as a beginner... :( hope someone can help.

Thank you very much in advance

Andras

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see in the code the editor should load properly.

First - you are missing a `</form>` tag. It should work almost all the time without it but just in case.
Second - you are missing input names.
Third - you are missing submit button.
Fourth - you are missing some code to process the submit

This piece of code should look like

```
if($_REQUEST["sumbit"] == "somevalue")
{
$param1 = mysql_real_escape_string ($_REQUEST["something1"]);
$param2 = mysql_real_escape_string ($_REQUEST["something2"]);
....
....
$sql = "insert into sometable (something,somethingelse) values('$param1','$param2')";
mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Also take a look at smarty or other template engines. Separating html from php can save a lot of white hairs in the long run.

Comment: Yes you are right and thanks for the hint. I am going to fix that I can.

Comment: I have done some changes I hope this is better, but I still can't grasp up how to get the CKEDITOR text as well?

Comment: from what I see you get it. It is in the pagecontent field.

Comment: ...//post?pr-name=tywrtyw&pr-end=wertweryt&menu=pr-pdf.php&pagecontent=%3Cp%3E%0D%0A%09werytwerywerywery%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A 

this is what I got in the browser search-bar, but I would love to save into my sql table:(

Comment: you already do $prcontent = mysql_real_escape_string ($_REQUEST["pagecontent"]); . Oh and change form method to post.

Comment: thanks again, I've done it but nothing comes to the SQL Table yet any idea how to track it?